Git fetch upto a specific tag
I am creating a GitHub workflow action, which will be triggered on the creation of a new tag.
Earlier I was using git pull --all in my script to pull the latest changes, during my deployment.
But when I tried to roll back to any of the previous tag versions, it was still pulling the latest changes, instead of the code changes made up to that specific tag reference.
So, Now I am using git fetch origin $(tag ref), and now I am neither able to pull the latest changes when I create a new tag for the latest deployment, nor I am able to deploy the code changes made up to that specific tag reference.
I have tried updating the script to use CI_Commit_SHA, instead of tag_ref, but that also does seem to work.
Can someone please help me find any issues in my gitlab.yml file:
#Deploy.yml

    name: Deploy to EC2
    
    on:
      push:
        tags:
          - '*'
    
    jobs:
      deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
        steps:
          - name: Checkout code
            uses: actions/checkout@v2
            with:
              ref: ${{ github.ref }} # Checkout the specific tag
    
          - name: Install SSH key
            run: |
              mkdir -p ~/.ssh
              echo "${{ secrets.AWS_SSH_KEY }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
              chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    
          - name: Add SSH key to known_hosts
            run: |
              ssh-keyscan -t rsa -H ${{ secrets.SERVER_PUBLIC_IP }} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    
          - name: Fetch only changes up to tag
            run: |
              git fetch origin ${{ github.ref }}
    
          - name: Deploy to EC2
            run: |
              ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@${{ secrets.SERVER_PUBLIC_IP }} 'bash -s' < ./Scripts/Script.sh

and here is my Script.sh
echo "********** Running Script .sh file **********"
cd
cd /home/ubuntu/React-1/FJ6-Prod-React/
npm i
npm run build
sudo cp -r build/* /var/www/html/
ls -l
pwd
sudo systemctl reload apache2
echo "********** End of Script .sh file 1 **********"


Are you sure it's a problem of fetching contents from GitLab? I suggest you check by running something like git log --oneline in your pipeline to see if you have of have not a git history. You probably also want to check out the fetch-depth option of the checkout action, which defaults to 1 for performance reasons.
I think the problem is a different one: You're checking out the repository and then trigger the script on your EC2 instance. How is the code loaded to the EC2 machine? I don't see this in your pipeline. Is it failing because it's not there at all or not updated?

I tried with fetch-depth option, but is also not working as expected. I tried to manually run the fetch command in ec2, instead of running it through the script, but this also did not fetch the changes from the repository. should I remove the fetch command from yml file and add it to the script?

and should I use fetch, followed by a checkout to that tag, in the script file?

1.) It seems odd to first checkout a specific commit, and then later fetch that same commit. The checkout would fail if you hadn't already fetched it. 2.) Why do wish to limit the fetch? You can still checkout whatever commit you want regardless of how much you've fetched. 3.) The --all argument to git pull is just passed to git fetch, and there it just means fetch all remotes. Unless you have more than one remote the --all does nothing.

Can you please share, what should be the ideal sequence of the git command, that I can use to pull the latest changes when a new tag is created, and to pull the changes up to the specific tag (in case of rollback) in the future? @TTT

Perhaps the problem is a misunderstanding, because in Git terms, this doesn't fully make sense: "pull the changes up to the specific tag". Note that "pull" is doing two separate commands: git fetch followed by git merge. My guess is you would be fine fetching everything, and then just checking out a specific tag that you want. So instead of pulling,  you would do git fetch followed by git switch <some-tag-name>. Perhaps you could test everything locally first, and then write your pipeline to match.

Btw, what is the reason you were thinking you want to "Fetch only changes up to tag"?
